# I want to find difference between 2 numbers stored in a file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Below is content of file.  I want to find out difference between each line of first field.

```
0.607401  # Tue Mar 27 04:30:01 IST 2018
0.607401  # Tue Mar 27 04:35:02 IST 2018
0.606325  # Tue Mar 27 04:40:02 IST 2018
0.606223  # Tue Mar 27 04:45:01 IST 2018
0.606167  # Tue Mar 27 04:50:02 IST 2018
0.605716  # Tue Mar 27 04:55:01 IST 2018
0.605716  # Tue Mar 27 05:00:01 IST 2018
0.607064  # Tue Mar 27 05:05:01 IST 2018
```

output:-

```
0
-0.001076
-0.000102
.019944
..
..
.001348
```

CODE:

```
awk '{s=$0;getline;print s-$0;next}' a.txt
```

However this does not work as expected...
Could you help me please?

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: awk '{s=$0;getline;print s-$0;next}' a.txt

this doesn;t work as expected

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` code:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{save=$1;next}NR>1{printf "%.6f\n",($1-save);save=$1}' file                                                                        
0.000000
-0.001076
-0.000102
-0.000056
-0.000451
0.000000
0.001348
```

and format the output as you want by modifying the `printf`.
The way you are currently doing will skip some lines!!!